# how to catch exception of MVC view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

In controller, try...catch can catch exception. How to catch exception in view? for example, a view may have code like:

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.MyID)%>
```

If Model is null, you will get exception when access the view. where to catch the exception and redirect user to a error page with user-friendly error message?

Comment: Which technology are you using?

Comment: MS ASP.NET MVC framework

Comment: I wouldn't use exceptions for non-exceptional behaviour and definitely not in the view.

Comment: Here's a solution for Orchard module views:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29536117/3936440

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the [HandleError] attribute to the top of your Controller class.  This way, any exception generated by your Controller will be handled and the user will be presented /Views/Shared/Error.aspx.  The model passed to that view is a System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo object.

The controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Default()
  {
    MyClass thing = MyClassFactory.Create();
    return View(thing);
  }
}
```

This is a for "last resort" exception handling.  David's answer is best for those cases you can think of ahead of time.

Answer (score 4):

Although I support David Liddle's answer ("This logic should be handled inside your Controller and not the View") I can also tell you that you should code defensively in general.

For example instead of

```
try
{
    Html.Encode(Model.MyID)
}
catch
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Error/500");
}
```

you should

```
if (Model == null)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    //.....
}
```

(ofcourse, again, don't put view selection logic in a view)

Comment: do I have to add `@` before `if` and `else`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use try/catch in a script block in the view:

```
@try
{    
  <div>typical Razor view stuff here...</div>
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  @<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('@ex.Message.Replace("'","\\'").Replace("\r\n","<br/>")');
  </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helped us resolve a production issue quickly. What I changed to your code was do a console.log instead of alert and I did log the entire "ex" object as JSON so that I can view all inner objects of "ex". Below is what I used in my script:
console.log('@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex)');

Comment: Unfortunately, the other suggested answers are fairly naive implementations. The reason why your suggested solution is the best solution, IMO, is in the scenario where you have complex views. When you utilize Render Partial inside of a view, you can utilize your suggested approach to trap exceptions for that specific render partial and provide specific logging in order to investigate/debug.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Elmah: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Answer (score 2):

This logic should be handled inside your Controller and not the View. For example if you are trying to view a Product with MyID that does not exist then redirect to an error page.

If an error has occured you could also redirect to an InvalidProduct view that would provide a more detailed error description/instructions.

Edit: In addition to peoples comments below to catch unhandled exceptions add the [HandleError] attribute either on your ActionResult method declaration or on the Controller (for all ActionResults).

```
[HandleError]
public ProductsController
{
    public ActionResult Show(int id)
    {
        Product p = //e.g. get product from db

        if (p == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error");
            //return RedirectToAction("InvalidProduct");
        }

        return View(p);
    }
```

Comment: What happens if there's an exception/error that you don't know about?

Comment: Your application should "fail fast". You can't handle an exception you don't know about anyway.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question. Of course it's better to have this kind of logic in the controller, but that's still not an answer. I'm working on an on-site prototype at a client where it takes about 15 minutes to upload files. Views can be edited in Notepad, but to edit the controller, I have to recompile on my machine and upload the binaries. So I'm using the Views to try out things. But I cannot see the exceptions, since they are hidden by some proxy between me and the server, and they don't appear in the logs. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't always catch every error in the controller, but hopefully your views should be lightweight enough where it's very unlikely to happen.

However, if an exception does get thrown in the view, you should have a custom 500 error page set up to redirect the user to just in case.  I believe you can set up a redirect like this in the Global.asax or it might be an IIS setting as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Matthew Groves that you can't always catch every error. Unfortunately in my case, I have a view that has 100 something variables. It's hard to account for all of them.

There's a variety of ways to catch errors here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine

In my case, I wanted to record the error that has occurred in the view with the data that was used in the controller. So I chose to override OnException in my controller. This way, during the action, I can store my data on the controller instance and then access it later in the OnException method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you want to redirect to an error action inside the cshtml:

```
                @{
                    try
                    {
                        Html.Action("GetCurrentUser", "Layout");
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Error");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This is handle, but not catch.