# ASP.NET MVC HandleError View Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, handleerror

I'm trying to implement exception handling in ASP.NET MVC3 using the HandleError attribute.

The code that I'm using looks like this:

```
[HandleError(Order = 1, ExceptionType = typeof(SocketsOfflineException), View="EndSystemDownError")]
```

This works as expected when the EndSystemDownError view is located in the "Shared" folder.  However, I have a number of Error views, and I want to separate them out into a folder specifically for Errors, called "Error".

So I pull the EndSystemDownError view out of the shared folder and into an "Error" subfolder in the Views folder.  I then update the View property to `~/Views/Error/EndSystemDownError`.  This however results in an exception stating that the view was not found.  I tried `/Views/Error/EndSystemDownError` as well, with the same results.

I have tried adding an `ErrorController` with an `EndSystemDownError` action, both as a troubleshooting measure, and because I would like to add some controller functionality to the view.  This has no effect.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Perhaps this is a bug in MVC, or maybe it doesn't support error views outside of the Shared folder, which would be disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your errors subfolder inside of the shared folder, you can refer to it by Errors/whatevererror.aspx and it should be fine.

I do this frequently. After all they are shared views. :)

Comment: This accomplishes the isolation of the error views that I am looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you cannot modify the location of those views. They should be in `~/Views/Shared`. You could specify the name though per exception type:

```
[HandleError(
    Order = 1, 
    ExceptionType = typeof(SocketsOfflineException), 
    View = "EndSystemDownError"
)]
```

where the `EndSystemDownError` view is located in `~/Views/Shared/EndSystemDownError.aspx`.

Comment: I would say so too. Since there is a lot of convention, and this is not different case. If I were searching for Error view, I would look for it first in ~/Views/Shared folder :)

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
[HandleError(Order = 1, ExceptionType = typeof(SocketsOfflineException), View="Error/EndSystemDownError")]
```

Comment: I tried both `Error/EndSystemDownError` and `/Error/EndSystemDownError` to no avail.

Comment: @David Marchelya, yeah, that's because it's not supported by the `HandleError` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Side note for Orchard module programming:

The `HandleError` attribute won't work in Orchard modules as Orchard implements a custom filter handling itself.

You need to implement a `FilterProvider` that overrides the `OnResultExecuted()` to catch exceptions thrown in a view.

See `src\Orchard\Exceptions\Filters\UnhandledExceptionFilter.cs`, it implements the common Orchard error page.